# Can I set the Kwallet opening timeout?

Tags: kde, kwallet

I am using KWallet to store various passwords on my pc. One of the passwords is for KMail. After login, when I do not enter a password, the opening dialogue times out and every single application asks for their respective password with their own dialogue, resulting in inconvenience on my side.

Can I increase the time after which the KWallet opening dialogue times out?